# Self Starting Functions for Exponential Decay Model in R

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, exponential

I'm working on a exponential decay model where I would like to estimate the decay rate. My current model uses a self-starting function, `SSasymp` from the `stats` package. I've also written a second model, where I just eyeball the starting parameters, which requires `minpack.lm` package. My question is, is there another way I can estimate the starting parameters to cross check the `SSasymp` function. I (think) I understand what the code is doing to estimate the starting parameters, but I wanted to get some feedback on wether the `SSasymp` is the right function to use with this data or if there is another function I could potentially use.

```
library(stats)
library(minpack.lm)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(Date=seq(1:66),
           Level=c(1438072839.75,   1397678053.5,   1358947420.5,   1313619938.25,  1269224528.25, 
1246776954.75,  1207201162.5,   1176229091.25,  1136063160, 1103721704.25,  1080591637.5,    
1048286667, 1017840460.5,   1001057052, 975815001,  943568665.5,    932026210.5,    916996593.75,    
903904288.5,    887578544.25,   871428547.5,    855417720,  843504839.25,   825835607.25,    
816060303.75,   803506361.25,   801213123,  797977217.25,   793483994.25,   780060123,  766265609.25,    
756172471.5,    746615497.5,    738002936.25,   723741644.25,   711969181.5,    696032998.5,     
686162453.25,   671953166.25,   674184571.5,    664739475,  641091932.25,   627358484.25,    
616740068.25,   602261552.25,   592440797.25,   584160403.5,    569780103.75,   556305753,   
551682927,  546535062,  537782506.5,    524251944.75,   519277188.75,   503598795,  498481312.5,     
487907885.25,   479760227.25,   474773064.75,   468246932.25,   460561701,  455266345.5,     
448451890.5,    447760119,  441236056.5,    438884417.25))

dfDecay<-nls(Level~ SSasymp(Date, Asym, R0, lrc), data = df)
dfFitted<-augment(dfDecay)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date,y=Level))+geom_point()+  geom_line( aes(y=dfFitted$.fitted), color="red")

dfDecay2<-nlsLM(Level~b*exp(-a*Date), 
                   data = df,
                   start= list(a=.01,b=1.5e+09),
                   algorithm = "LM")
fitDecay2<-augment(dfDecay2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date,y=Level))+geom_point()+  geom_line( aes(y=fitDecay2$.fitted), color="red")
```

Comment: Apologies, just added them

Comment: Very sorry, added two more libraries and tested to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344966/self-starting-functions-for-exponential-decay-model-in-r/61388357#61388357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding starting values:

1. Take logs of both sides and fit with a linear model.
2. The parameters should be of similar magnitude to avoid numerical problems so use `Level/1e9` in place of `Level`.  This just changes the units in which Level is measured.
3. Using starting values from the linear model, `nls` should be sufficient.

This gives:

```
fm0 <- lm(log(Level/1e9) ~ Date, df)
st <- list(a = exp(coef(fm0)[[1]]), b = -coef(fm0)[[2]])
nls(Level/1e9 ~ a * exp(-b * Date ), df, start = st)
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: Level/1e+09 ~ a * exp(-b * Date)
   data: df
     a      b 
1.3532 0.0183 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.08055

Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.023e-07
```

Comment: This is a great response, thank you! One question though, iwhat made you choose to divide by 1e9?

Comment: Look at `mean(df$Level)` and since the specific number does not matter just use something close that is easy to write.

Comment: I'm trying to better understand this in my head. I know choosing starting parameters is very important for non-linear models. When running the self-starting model and the model you wrote above I get different decay rate results which results in half-lives of +-20 months. Why would this model be considered more favorable to the self-starting function? I understand your model, but I'm unsure how to interpret the difference in decay rates.

Comment: Check the deviance, i.e. residual sum of squares -- deviance(fm), of the two results and compare.  Also be sure you are using the same model in each case.